# Why was "Hourglass" deleted?

Tags: discussion, migration, historical-lock

I went to cite an answer I had written to a puzzle here, called Hourglass.  I found the puzzle--which had 51 upvotes and 13 answers (including mine) had been deleted:

[Code Golf: Hourglass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683857/)

The question text for those without privileges to read it was:

> ### The challenge
>
> The shortest code by character count to output an hourglass according to user input.
>
> Input is composed of two numbers: First number is a greater than 1 integer that represents the height of the bulbs, second number is a percentage (0 - 100) of the hourglass' capacity.
>
> The hourglass' height is made by adding more lines to the hourglass' bulbs, so size 2 (the minimal accepted size) would be:
>
> ```
> _____
> \   /
>  \ /
>  / \
> /___\
> ```
>
> Size 3 will add more lines making the bulbs be able to fit more 'sand'.
>
> Sand will be drawn using the character `x`. The top bulb will contain N percent 'sand' while the bottom bulb will contain (100 - N) percent sand, where N is the second variable.
>
> 'Capacity' is measured by the amount of spaces () the hourglass contains. Where percentage is not exact, it should be rounded up.
>
> Sand is drawn from outside in, giving the right side precedence in case percentage result is even.
>
> ### Test cases
>
> ```
> Input:
>    3 71%
> Output:
>    _______
>    \x  xx/
>     \xxx/
>      \x/
>      / \
>     /   \
>    /__xx_\
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Input:
>    5 52%
> Output:
>    ___________
>    \         /
>     \xx   xx/
>      \xxxxx/
>       \xxx/
>        \x/
>        / \
>       /   \
>      /     \
>     /  xxx  \
>    /xxxxxxxxx\
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Input:
>    6 75%
> Output:
>    _____________
>     \x         x/
>      \xxxxxxxxx/
>       \xxxxxxx/
>        \xxxxx/
>         \xxx/
>          \x/
>          / \
>         /   \
>        /     \
>       /       \
>      /         \
>     /_xxxxxxxxx_\
> ```
>
> Code count includes input/output (i.e full program).

It turns out *all the old stackoverflow code golf Q&A*--from an era prior to establishment of the separate [Code Golf Site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), were **just deleted**.

Funny, that.  Because once upon a time, when I linked to a long answer on my blog I was told *not to use a link* because "blogs go down" and "StackOverflow has more at stake".  O rly?  Seems I'm better at archiving and keeping all my links working than StackOverflow is...

(Is *that* a world you want to live in...the one where ***I'm*** more reliable than SO?  Didn't think so.  But until this is fixed, in protest I have reverted and [linked to my more reliable blog](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2444508/revisions) :-/)

It would not be hard to fix--even if the decision is not to migrate them to CodeGolf.SE.  Just lock them, keep inbound links working, but drop them off the search rank.  Etc.  Consider how this kind of thing was handled:

[What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)

That would be far preferable to careless deletion.  Personally I'd favor migration to codegolf.se, but, if that's something people don't want then it doesn't have to happen.

Comment: All of the old code golf questions on SO were deleted. I'm sure one of the mods also has a source for that.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Hum.  Why not migrate?

Comment: @Dr.Rebmu Questions older than 60 days (the biggest majority of that tag) cannot be migrated anymore.

Comment: A comment on the question says the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683857/code-golf-hourglass#comment33152249_1683857

Comment: @ProgramFOX Oh, I see.  Because after 60 days they're moved onto hard drives in space?  ["Because it's airing during...a children's program?"](http://extratv.com/2014/07/17/watch-neil-patrick-harris-stars-in-hilarious-new-heineken-light-ad/)

Comment: @Dr.Rebmu See this Meta.SE question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/229438

Comment: Note that this was a bit of a special case, as an entire tag was "spun off" into its own site. One wonders if they could/should have used the same tool that was used to do the MSO/MSE split. Too late now I would imagine.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET *"Too late now I would imagine."* Per my update, the data is still there.  Hence "Too late" is only a macro for "your problem isn't a priority".  I think that's a slippery slope of not keeping your system working... why not keep it working?

Comment: Not disagreeing with you. On the contrary, I think that (if the Code Golf community agrees) a mass migration would be *great*. Realistically, I'm not sure if it will happen though. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: A mass migration of old questions from Stack Overflow to Code Golf would do nothing to build the community at Code Golf. It would give the impression of a much larger and more active community, but there would be no CG users behind most of the migrated questions and answers.

Comment: @BilltheLizard You seem to lack empathy for the historical archiving issue.  Whatever consequences you are fretting about for the influx of data to CodeGolf is outweighed by the mass deletion.

Comment: Golf questions got deleted.  Nobody noticed until today.

Comment: How do you know if the consequences are outweighed if you don't know what they are?

Comment: @HostileFork whoever tries to delete Bill, only gets a tail.

Comment: See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/922/adopt-and-reopen-sos-closed-code-golf-questions, for CG's take on importing old questions.

Comment: @Bill: I think that should be for the CG.SE community to decide. Personally, as a reasonably active user there, I think the site has grown enough by now that it could easily accommodate a few dozen (or even a few hundred) old migrated questions, especially if the alternative is condemning those questions to oblivion.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm not the one who decided it, Stack Exchange did. That's the network-wide policy on mass migrations.

Comment: @Bill: I was referring to your comment that it "would do nothing to build the community". I really don't see how that's anyone's business but the community's (although, of course, the community would then need to convince SE of this, to actually get the questions migrated). In any case, apparently, SE staff *can* manually override the 60 day limit, if there's sufficient consensus that the question(s) should be moved.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen actually, that's what SE decided with all communities. Nothing good has ever happened with those actions, why repeat them?

Comment: @Braiam I still think that from an archival standpoint, deleting the questions is outright irresponsible.  If you want to remove them from search results, okay.  But that's now a dead link.  In this case a dead link from my code golfing archives, where I had *trusted* that the link would be managed properly to store the definition of the puzzle.  Whatever happened to "this question is of archival interest and is not a good example of what a question today would be"?  Instead, deleting 51 upvote questions with good answers is "normal" now and collateral damage is acceptable?  Says who?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is exactly why we created [the Historical Lock](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> To be clear: most of these are not great examples of questions that should be asked today… But some of them are, quite frankly, brilliant – and losing them entirely just because they aren’t a good fit for our strict Q&A format is wrong. For now, we’ve provided a “Historical Artifact” lock that completely freezes a question and its answers, preventing all further editing, voting, answering, and flagging. It will also remove it from the usual lists of questions on the site while allowing it to remain fully accessible and visible to everyone with a link to it.

I've gone through and locked [all the old, deleted, CodeGolf questions that scored 10 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-golf%5D%20locked%3A1), excluding things with the tag that weren't really codegolf. This should cover *most* of the questions that could be considered "historically valuable"; if you run across more, just flag them and request a lock.

Comment: This is a great step... although I wonder if a post isn't actively offensive and contains information what the reason for not historically locking *everything* would be.  Maybe there could be a next "tier" of irrelevancy, kind of like "this comment has been hidden" on some sites, where you have to go an extra step to click a button to see the content...and it's shown using some kind of script trickery that "absolutely" keeps it out of search engines?

Answer (score 8):

One option is the answer I got when I asked to [migrate an old popular deleted question to a different site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178865/request-to-migrate-a-popular-deleted-question). Essentially, if you think you see a good question worthy of resurrection:

- Ask it again on the other site (or ping the original asker, encouraging them to do so)
- Ping the writer of your favourite answer, inviting them to copy and paste it back from the dead

This resurrects quality content and gives that new more focussed community the opportunity to see if they can do better.

Obviously it's polite to credit the original. Since Code Golf is competitive, you might want to ping the original answerer before asking rather than after, so people who recognise the question can't 'cheat' and steal the answer. Or if you trust people, just ask them not to do that.

---

The impression I get is, there's resistance to wholesale migration since it would bring the bad back from the dead with the good. But case-by-case where you think something is worthy - why not?

Comment: I've updated with my current opinion, which is, if migration is considered too disruptive...just leave them and lock them.  Wholesale deletion was the wrong call.  If someone wants to post a a new code golf round with the old puzzle, they at least have something to link to and attribute as the source.