# It's time to reach community consensus on what to do with highly-upvoted but off-topic posts

Tags: discussion, scope, old-questions, needs-more-focus, historical-lock

The issue of what the *hell* to do with old, highly-upvoted questions with very useful answers is something that is brought up time and time again. Recently, I've felt it coming to something of a head, and with it, opening up a discussion of a larger topic, the idea of "off-topic" questions that can still receive extremely useful answers.

In [the case of outdated posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284187/why-was-hourglass-deleted), the argument seems to be primarily between deletion or the historical lock. But what about more generally?

We used to have the "too localized" close reason, which has since been removed. That's fine. Questions that are too localized are unlikely to help anyone else in the future (at least when the reason is used correctly). But what about too broad?

Is [asking how JavaScript closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) **too broad**? What about [a question asking about the intricacies of branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)? How about [preventing SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)? Or perhaps [the most efficient way to clone an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)?

These questions are broad, but *someone* took the time to write *amazing* answers. Should these be closed? Should they be locked? Or do these get special exemptions from the usual rule?

Whatever my opinions are, I want to see what the community thinks. I think it's an incredibly important issue for determining the site's future, [and the developers think so, too](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/03/podcast-63-the-plumbers-up-to-67-coins/). Let's try and figure this out the best way we know how: a discussion on Meta!

Comment: _"Let's try and figure this out the best way we know how: a discussion on Meta!"_; you really lost me at this... the best way of doing something is rarely a discussion; it's a cogent argument put forward by a knowledgeable person that drives a group to agree with the conclusions put forward (that's why Shog's successful) - no discussion. It's possible to find one of these in an answer to a discussion, but I can rarely be bothered to wade through 50 to find the rare answer that displays these qualities.

Comment: @Ben This is not intended to be a be-all and end-all discussion. This is intended to be a preliminary discussion. That's what Meta is all about, and ideally, we can come to a stronger conclusion armed with the knowledge from this discussion. It helps to have information, after all. I want to see what the community thinks.

Comment: (If you don't want to participate, that's fine, but I still think this would be valuable.)

Comment: The only thing you really can do wrong with these old questions is bringing them up over and over again and assume some brilliant new insight will emerge.  This has been endlessly debated before, enough already.

Comment: I'm happy to participate I just have experience on how to form agreement on a subject - committee is rarely the best way; especially when the basic premise put forward is contentious. You've assumed that all of your listed questions are off-topic. I don't think they are. I understand that you're seeing this sort of question get raised on meta more than you're used to, but this really does go in cycles. It only happens every month or three.

Comment: Isn't the consensus already to close it if it doesn't meet today's standards, and/or give it a historical lock? It kind of really depends on the case, I don't think a blanket action can be made here.

Comment: @JasonC Right, I agree, that's sort of why I bring it up. What about new questions, though, not just old ones? This is just as much a question about whether or not the current "too broad" reason is valid as it is about old questions.

Comment: New questions case-by-case as well. The timestamp is mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If a question meets the close criteria, close it.  This applies just as much to Too Broad as it does for off topic posts, or any other close reason.  The existence of answers to the post has nothing to do with this consideration.  Posts aren't left open just because they have good answers.

If the answers are particularly valuable then that's a reason to not delete the posts, not a reason to leave them open.  If there is a concern with users deleting these posts despite the fact that they are providing a *significant* amount of value, then the post can be locked, to indicate that it really doesn't belong here, but we don't want to delete it.  It can also be locked if the post is continually being reopened despite being clearly off topic for the site.

Comment: If this were true, we'd still have all the old close criteria around. This is just as much about figuring out how to come up with *better* criteria than making informed judgements based on existing answers. The close reasons evolve over time, and I think people recognize that some of the current ones aren't serving their purpose.

Comment: @AlexisKing What?  No.  There have honestly been very few changes as to what types of questions can actually be closed, largely the close reasons have just been reworded to make them clearer.  When they have actually changed (which is very rarely, and not significantly), it was because the questions that should actually be closed has changed.  This has nothing to do with not closing questions that meet a closure criteria.  The vast majority of historically locked questions merited closure *when asked*, but just weren't closed because people liked the content.

Comment: Too localized? Lacks minimal understanding? These were abused. They're gone now.

Comment: @AlexisKing They were removed because they were abused and *not used for what they meant*.  That's not changing what should be closed, but rather changing the wording of the reasons to prevent people from abusing them to close questions that don't merit closure.  That's clarifying the reasons, not changing what is or is not in scope.

Comment: To be fair to the OP this doesn't really address the essential question, which seems to be: _There are a load of questions which don't "display effort", I therefore believe they are off-topic. **But**, they have really good answers; are they still off-topic?_

Comment: @Ben How does it not?  If the question merits closure, close it.  If it contains valuable content, don't delete it after it has been closed.  The quality of the answers has no bearing on whether or not the question should be closed.

Comment: You not defining exactly what merits closure; hence the discussion. Personally, I disagree with the premise - an answer can make a question. The trick in most cases would be getting that answer.

Comment: @Ben You're right, I'm not defining what merits closure.  It's irrelevant to the question (the question is asking if we should refrain from closing a question that merits closure), and also an extremely broad topic if you get into all of the details.  The short version of course is that a question merits closure if it meets the criteria for any of the given close reasons.  There is no way for an answer to a question to change whether that question meets any of the close reasons defined.  Someone trying to answer a broad question doesn't make that question any less broad, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Disclaimer***: I wrote this question, and here's my opinion on the matter. It is far from definitive, and more than anything, I want to see others' opinions, too.

Recently, there have been some squabbles over what to do about old, highly-upvoted content that doesn't really belong on the site anymore. There seems to be a cabal of users that have decided that deleting this content is a good idea, and I completely disagree. The historical lock exists for a reason, and I would not hesitate to use it instead of simply nuking an entire thread outright.

Still, the issue is really more nuanced than that. Let me outline my general philosophy.

- Things that are "too broad" but have good answers are probably still on-topic. These don't even necessarily need to be locked, though protecting them is probably a good idea. This was discussed on a recent SE podcast, and it's an ongoing problem, and I'm very interested in helping to find the right solution.
- On the other hand, things that are mostly opinion based or are otherwise not constructive should usually be locked. As long as the content is good, it should be kept around...
- ...*unless* it's destined to be outdated. Questions that ask "what is a good library to do *X*" eventually rot to the point where they're just providing misinformation. The historical lock doesn't help here because it prevents inaccuracies from being fixed but keeps them around for all to see. Sometimes, I endorse deletion of these kinds of questions.

There are some questions which are "timeless", at least to a point, even if they're very broad subjects. The current reason we close questions as "too broad" is because we feel like the OP is asking *far too much* of the members of this site. Really, it's to discourage those sorts of questions from being asked.

It doesn't work. There are lots of questions that are *very* broad but have *fantastic answers*. Should we be feeding all new questions like that to the Roomba? Is there any more room for great answers of sizable scope on Stack Overflow?

I don't know. I don't have a good solution. The problem is that, yes, it's true, a large portion of the overly-broad questions on Stack Overflow are terrible, almost impossible to answer, and should be closed. But are we foreclosing on a type of question with potentially stellar answers? Aren't we a repository of knowledge in addition to a Q&A site?

Just like "too localized" was too easily abused, I'd posit that "too broad" is similarly broken, though in less obvious ways. Just like "too localized" was forked into various more specific counterparts, it's time to do the same with "too broad". I don't know exactly what the replacements should be, but I'm beginning to be relatively convinced that this policy needs to be adjusted to keep *this kind* of content, some of the best content out there, on the site.